# Angular 2 QuickStart Live-server error

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and I have been trying to learn more about angular2.
I have followed the getting started guide to create the angular2-quickstart project.
However when I am running the command npm start, the browser start but everything fails after 1 second.
Below is the content of my npm error log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'lite' ]
2 info using npm@3.3.12
3 info using node@v5.2.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prelite', 'lite', 'postlite' ]
5 info lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~prelite: angular2-quickstart@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~prelite: no script for prelite, continuing
7 info lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~lite: angular2-quickstart@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~lite: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~lite: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/bakary/angular2-quickstart/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/bakary/angular2-quickstart/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
10 verbose lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~lite: CWD: /home/bakary/angular2-quickstart
11 silly lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~lite: Args: [ '-c', 'lite-server' ]
12 silly lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~lite: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~lite: Failed to exec lite script
14 verbose stack Error: angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 lite: `lite-server`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:232:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:88:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:173:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:88:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:173:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:819:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:212:5)
15 verbose pkgid angular2-quickstart@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd /home/bakary/angular2-quickstart
17 error Linux 3.16.0-50-generic
18 error argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "lite"
19 error node v5.2.0
20 error npm  v3.3.12
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 lite: `lite-server`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 lite script 'lite-server'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     lite-server
23 error You can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Can you help me figure out what I am doing wrong ?

Regards

Comment: I solved problem with mpn and lite-server [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34335340/angular2-quickstart-npm-start-is-not-working-correctly)

Comment: Do you run the command with administrator rights?

Comment: Thanks @TomekMiszczyk ! The solution is to update the sysctl.conf in ubuntu.

Comment: This doesn't help for me. Any other ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 59):

Change the Package.json Scripts Settings

```
"start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\",
```

to

```
"start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
```

angular 2 has moved from system js to webpack, find the sample app where you guys can get started with angular2 + webpack + Typescript https://github.com/IgnatiusAndrew/angular2-webpack-starter

Comment: This fixed it for me.

Comment: As said, this isn't a fix you, TSC fail because you have an issue in your code. In my case it was due to a import that I forgot to change after moving some dataobject class file in a subfolder.

Comment: Why there were the need of run tsc twice? Was it right?

Comment: @tt_Gantz 's comment is better.

Comment: This is the answer for me Thanks .I was following the video course from scotch.io for angular2 and most probably packge.json was outdated nowadays and your explanation looks totally correct.

Answer (score 10):

The solution is to add this line in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288
```

and type in the console `sudo sysctl -p`

Comment: this solved the issue, thanks. However, a little explanation would be nice: http://linux.die.net/man/8/sysctl and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13751/kernel-inotify-watch-limit-reached were quite instructive

Comment: How do i do this in Windows 10 ?

Comment: @Shakee93 .... its time to go linux ... :P .... better now then never =D

Answer (score 5):

A lot of people said removing `tsc` from the `package.json` start script helped them. In this case the problem is with typescript finding an issue in your code.

Try running `tsc` from the terminal and see what the output is and fix it. If the issue  was with `tsc` then fixing this should remove the error.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem too. It seems what it is problem with dependences of `lite-server`.

I changed line in `packages.json`:

```
"start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"node .\" "
```

This solution helps me to investigate Angular2 further, but will be good to solve problem with `lite-server` later.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just forgot to run

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing:

"concurrently": "^3.0.0",

to

"concurrently": "^2.0.0",

in package.json

Answer (score 0):

In my case one of my TypeScript `import` statement paths where incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

In Package.json script instead of removing `tsc` from `start` section I defined it as below:

```
"tsc": "tsc",
"tsc:w": "tsc -w",
```

So the `"scripts"` now looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\",
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved not being able to start npm start error:

```
    tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"
```

(after all the above attempts failed) with: in package.json do:
        "tsc": "tsc",
        "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
        "start": "concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",