# events.js:154 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: npm, angular

I got error, when I create angular 2 application. I follow [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) create sample application. when I run

```
npm start
```

I got bellow error,

```
events.js:154
   throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
   ^

Error: watch node_modules/weinre/web/weinre/target/WiRuntimeImpl.amd.js ENOSPC
 at exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
 at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1313:19)
 at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1341:11)
 at createFsWatchInstance (/home/mts/project/testSails1/frontend/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
 at setFsWatchListener (/home/mts/project/testSails1/frontend/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
 at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/mts/project/testSails1/frontend/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:228:14)
 at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleFile (/home/mts/project/testSails1/frontend/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:255:21)
 at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/mts/project/testSails1/frontend/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:473:21)
 at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
```

I got npm logs like this,

```
 npm
   ERR! Linux 3.19.0-51-generic
  npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "lite"
  npm ERR! node v5.6.0
  npm ERR! npm  v3.8.0
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! frontend@1.0.0 lite: `lite-server`
  npm ERR! Exit status 1
  npm ERR! 
  npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@1.0.0 lite script 'lite-server'.
  npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
  npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the frontend package,
  npm ERR! not with npm itself.
  npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
  npm ERR!     lite-server
  npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
  npm ERR!     npm bugs frontend
  npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
  npm ERR!     npm owner ls frontend
  npm ERR!
   There is likely additional logging output above.

  npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
  npm ERR!     /home/mts/project/testSails1/frontend/npm-debug.log
  npm run lite exited with code 1
```

How I solve this?

Comment: Check these two issues [#7138](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7138) and [#6097](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6097)

Comment: See especially this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35317737/217408

Comment: If closing the port is not working for you , see this answer > https://stackoverflow.com/a/52441411/6665568

Comment: This Worked flawlessly for me :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/52441411/6665568

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My previous `package.json` is,

```
 {
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",    
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install" 
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "systemjs": "0.19.22",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.2",
    "typings":"^0.6.8"
  }
}
```

I added to `package.json` like this,

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run http\" ",    
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "http": "http-server -p 3000 -a 127.0.0.1 -o",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install" 
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "systemjs": "0.19.22",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.2",
    "typings":"^0.6.8"
  }
}
```

now project working find.

there are change only `lite ==> http` then working find

Comment: Could you specify what's the difference between your previous package.json and the one that solved your problem? Others users may reach this question.

Comment: Worked for me. Do not forget to run 
`npm install` first

Answer (score 16):

That means you have already run the app, then you attempted to run it one more time without stopping the last run. Therefore, it was conflicted. You must stop the last run <=> click the stop button (red-square button on debug panel).

Comment: no, I stop it. i try lot of day

Comment: Indeed. I find this every helpful.

Comment: You saved my days bro, thanks a lot.