# node.js error message events.js:183 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: node.js, botframework, sublimetext

Playing around Microsoft's botframework, when I try to run the app.js file, which is the main file of the bot, the first time is fine, after I close the bot emulator, and all programs, and run the app.js again, this error message pops out

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3978
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1351:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1392:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1476:7)
    at Server.listen (C:\Users\yu\Documents\GitHub\BotBuilder-
Samples\Node\cards-AdaptiveCards\node_modules\restify\lib\server.js:404:32)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\yu\Documents\GitHub\BotBuilder-
Samples\Node\cards-AdaptiveCards\app.js:10:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
```

I found some solution to this, It looks like the port 3978 was taken when I run the js file for the second time, and I have to use cmd to find which task is using that port, and then kill the task.

```
C:\>netstat -aon|findstr 3978
```

so this one is taking the port, although I already closed all programs

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:3978           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       13140
TCP    [::]:3978              [::]:0                 LISTENING       13140
```

actually it is node.exe itself, it still running at background

```
C:\Users\yu>tasklist|findstr 13140
node.exe                     13140 Console                    1     42,064 K
```

and I need to kill it

```
C:\Users\yu>taskkill /f /t /im node.exe
```

Is there a way to not always repeat doing this when I want to run the file more than one time, it just starts to go wired today, and I mean for all different app.js files, include offical sample code. For the past one month, everything was fine, the IDE I am using is sublime text 3, node.js version is 8.9.4 lts

Comment: How exactly are you running app.js the first time?  If you are using sublime to build and execute, you can also use it to kill node.exe process that is hosting app.js.

Comment: Running app.js the first time means I run it after the computer boots, and  how to kill the node.exe by using sublime text?

Comment: nevermind, I just wrote a bat file to kill the node.exe, since it always take the port 3978, thanks for your help

Comment: "i run it after the computer boots" -- yes, but HOW do you run app.js?  From the command line ("node.exe app.js"), from within Sublime using shortcuts?    Using a .bat file to kill the node process seems odd, and should not be necessary.

Comment: ok, I see the reason now, I added a javascript build system to the sublime text(got from here https://pawelgrzybek.com/javascript-console-in-sublime-text/), so I only need to press f7 to run the code, to lazy to type node app.js in node.js command prompt, seems like this issue only appear when I use sublime text to run it

Answer (score 18):

### This is a very common issue and can be easily fixed by either of the below methods.

1. Try to close the process that is using your port.

   > **`netstat -tulnp | grep <port_number>`**
2. Installing the below pakcage fixed it for me forever.

   > **`npm install ws@3.3.2 --save-dev --save-exact`**
3. Run this command in your terminal :

   > **`echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p`**

   **For Arch Linux add this line to /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf:**

   `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288`

   Then execute:

   `sysctl --system`

   This will also persist across reboots.

   https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers#the-technical-details

Either one of the solutions will work . If not then restart your system and check again.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and your answer worked perfectly! Thank you

Answer (score 6):

If you are on **mac**, to make sure nothing is running on the same port, do:

```
killall node
```

and restart your app.

Comment: the solution works.. works well in ubuntu machine as well

Answer (score 3):

The port you are listening to is already being listened by another process.

When I faced to this error I killed the process using Windows PowerShell (because I used Windows)

1. open the windows powershell
2. type `ps` and then you can get list of processes
3. find the process named **node**, and note the **Id**
4. type `Stop-process <Id>`

I think that it is help for windows users.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same problem and tried many ways but finally got this ,this work well

npm install ws@3.3.2 --save-dev --save-exact

refer to this link for more clarifications 
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2922

Answer (score 1):

Try specify a different port before you run the node.js application.

For example, if you have collision on port 3978, set a different port before you start the server.js:

`export PORT=3979`

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue using this command in my terminal on Linux.

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

Even I was also getting the error while running node server.
i.e events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
In my case, I was getting that error because I had changed Mysql port number 3306 to 3307 while installing. I recovered from from that error by changing Mysql port number to 3306, and now its running.

Answer (score 0):

I did also face the same problem. Installing of `npm install ws@3.3.2 --save-dev --save-exact` was not fix this. Later I came to know that there is an another website hosted by IIS in the same port where I configured for Node JS express server. Stopping of IIS website can get rid out of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Find the process that is using the port and kill it.**

Assuming the server port is 8000.

> 1) C:> netstat -aon | findstr 8000

This command will return the Process ID (PID).

> 2) C:> taskkill /F /PID 7848

This command will kill the Process by PID.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you open another project without having closed the one you were already using, remember to always use Ctrl+c when you finish using a project. Try rebooting your PC and it should work again. At least that's what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You might be running some other application on the same port, and it is still running.
So you can't run two applications on the same port.

Answer (score 0):

faced with the same issue

try to watch install watchman or upgrade it.

```
  brew install watchman

  brew upgrade watchman
```

Answer (score 0):

> **“listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use”**

When this **EADDRINUSE** issue has happened, in order to resolve it, you need to kill the process manually.

Hit the below command on the terminal.

```
lsof -i tcp:3000
```

> (In place of 3000 you can use ur already used port.) which may look like in the below error
>
> Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000

It will show the below details.

```
COMMAND PID   USER  FD  TYPE DEVICE             SIZE/OFF NODE NAME 
node    56735 maheshvirus 54u IPv4 0x932b78ub29n4b 0t0 TCP *:strexec-s
```

To get rid of this issue kill the current PID using the below command.

```
sudo kill -9 56735
```

Re-run the app and see the magic.

Answer (score 0):

use command bellow command to check if there is proccess running on this port

```
lsof -i:PORT NUMBER
```

In Your case it should be like this `lsof -i:3978`

- NOTE: you might need to use sudo before the command if the process running by root

when you find the process there are two solutions:

1- stop that process.

`kill $(lsof -t -i:8080)` if the process started by root use `sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:8080)`.

2- run your JS app on different port.

Answer (score -1):

I experienced the same problem. Installing this package solved it permanently:

```
npm install ws@3.3.2 --save-dev --save-exact
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of Janith Udara's answer.