# Angularjs 2 Quickstart - Npm run error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have tried the angular2 5 Min quickstart from https://angular.io/guide/quickstart. All files were created by copy & paste because i am lazy and because of possible faults. I preferred the TypeScript version. At the end, i must compile and start with "npm start". I do this as admin. my OS is Windows 10.
After start, I get some errors. this is the npm-debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@2.9.1
3 info using node@v0.12.3
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
5 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
6 info prestart angular2-quickstart@1.0.0
7 info start angular2-quickstart@1.0.0
8 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 info angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 Failed to exec start script
10 verbose stack Error: angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" `
10 verbose stack Exit status 2
10 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:213:16)
10 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:110:17)
10 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
10 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
10 verbose stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
10 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
11 verbose pkgid angular2-quickstart@1.0.0
12 verbose cwd C:\web\angular2-quickstart
13 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
14 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
15 error node v0.12.3
16 error npm  v2.9.1
17 error code ELIFECYCLE
18 error angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" `
18 error Exit status 2
19 error Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" '.
19 error This is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart package,
19 error not with npm itself.
19 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
19 error     tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite"
19 error You can get their info via:
19 error     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
19 error There is likely additional logging output above.
20 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Can anybody help me get the quickstart app to start? 
I also tried to start the index.html in Firefox ( because the .ts files are all translated in .js files ) but nothing happens.

Comment: try this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34335340/angular2-quickstart-npm-start-is-not-working-correctly/36790628#36790628

Comment: @clsah Yes follow that question link and ensure you have properly installed node, concurrently, and lite server, and typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my fault. the file app.component.ts was empty. i filled it with the correct content and "run npm start" and it works. the lite browser starts, i see "My first Angular 2 App" and i will be happy until the end of my days.