# Conflicting UNMET Dependency hell angular@2 / rxjs zone.js

Tags: angular, dependencies, npm-install

I believe I have successfully resolved this kind of issue beforehand, more or less following the approach outlined in this popular question:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35738361/108350

If you skip to the bottom the reported errors indicate the

- rxjs@**5.0.0-beta.12**
- zone.js@^**0.6.21**

By this stage (as shown below from my `bash` session) both of these modules are installed *first*.

```
 node $ sudo npm -g --save install zone.js@^0.6.21
/usr/lib
└── zone.js@0.6.25 

node $ sudo npm -g --save install  rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12
/usr/lib
└── rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12
```

... And, yet; **`angular@core`** reports:

```
  node $ sudo npm -g --save install  @angular/core
  /usr/lib
  ├── @angular/core@2.0.1 
  ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12
  └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@^0.6.21

  npm WARN @angular/core@2.0.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
  npm WARN @angular/core@2.0.1 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.6.21 but none was installed.
```

Install reports an: `unmet peer dependency`, on both modules.  Even after I have

- `npm remove -g` *each of these three packages*

This appears to be circular to me.  I am fairly sure the version numberings on the installed packages and the Unmet error are the same versions.

This kind of tautological dependency hell seems common place my search on:

- `[angular2] unmet peer dependency`

Rapidly yielded 23 results mostly on beta-s or different package combinations.  I am forced to apologies for harsh words about Maven JAR-hell in the past.

Is there a solution?  Am I (perhaps?) misreading the meaning of the messages?

As a follow-up query, is there a tool or web page that can do a  "*dry run*" to validate these kind of install issues??

*... my thanks in advance*.

---

*codicil* (2nd update, 2016-09-28) ...

- thanks due to @David L for giving me the idea

I ran the following `npm` instruction just now, with the ***surprise*** result (as shown):

```
node $ sudo npm -g --save install   rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12  zone.js@^0.6.21  @angular/core  -registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
/usr/lib
├── @angular/core@2.0.1 
├── rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 
└── zone.js@0.6.25
```

Thus and all-in-one `npm install` appears to be a valid work-around to what I (now) consider a bug.

Given this result I guess people's `package.json` files are *safe*. Apparently being handled in the same transaction/operation is Significant (albeit undocumented; based on the number of NOENT and UNMET questions I saw while trying to *eek* this one).

I'm now considering how to out-source this part of the equation ...

Enough said; this recipe worked in this case.  The steps I applied in the first instance have worked many, many times in the past.

1. Clean-up / reset
2. Work from the independent to
3. The most dependent

Given this result, that's what we used to call *co-dependent* in the '80-s, or entanglement.

Progressing what I was originally doing, I've discovered that ALL these modules MUST be in the same `npm install` for it to work without errors or warnings.

```
  node $ sudo npm -g --save install tsickle rxjs \ 
  @angular/core @angular/platform-browser zone.js  \
  @angular/compiler   @angular/common   \
  @angular/compiler-cli \
  @angular/http   @angular/forms  typescript \
  @angular/platform-server   -registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

  /usr/bin/tsickle -> /usr/lib/node_modules/tsickle/build/src/main.js
  /usr/bin/ngc -> /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/main.js
  /usr/bin/ng-xi18n -> /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/extract_i18n.js
  /usr/bin/tsc -> /usr/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc
  /usr/bin/tsserver -> /usr/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsserver
  /usr/lib

  ├── @angular/common@2.0.1 
  ├── @angular/compiler@2.0.1 
  ├─┬ @angular/compiler-cli@0.6.3 
  │ └─┬ @angular/tsc-wrapped@0.3.0
  │   └── tsickle@0.1.7 
  ├── @angular/core@2.0.1 
  ├── @angular/forms@2.0.1 
  ├── @angular/http@2.0.1 
  ├── @angular/platform-browser@2.0.1 
  ├─┬ @angular/platform-server@2.0.1 
  │ └── parse5@1.3.2 
  ├── rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 
  ├── typescript@2.0.3 
  └── zone.js@0.6.25
```

My BIG surprise here is that (*now*) **typescript** is a required dependency for `@angular/compiler-cli`.  I was happily using Javascript before with no typescript.  Hopefully this is a *glitch* fixed when sanity returns.

Perhaps this extra update adds nothing to the *codicil* because it seems as if the `npm install` problem is laziness:

- `npm` is Not looking very well at the resident bits already *installed*

As far as I can see based on the results this week.  Still it is only Wednesday :-)

Comment: If you install all three packages locally instead of globally, does anything change?

Comment: @DavidL ... thanks for your suggesting.  As you see there is fruit.  Although I didn't need to use plain non-global.  However that's kind of behaviour usually represents an some kind of entanglement imho.  Things probably need to be factored out to more-basic sub-*bits*.