# Angular2 seed: npm start has gulp error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular

When I run `npm start` on the angular2 seed file i'm trying to experiment with it's sending me back an error saying that it fails at the gulp script. My node and npm are up-to-date, so it can't be that. Has any one else had this error or have any suggestions as to what it might be?

The angular seed file: https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed
My Node version: v6.2.1
My NPM version: 3.10.1

```
charlottes-mbp:angular2-seed 2 charlotte$ npm start

> angular2-seed@1.0.0 start /Users/charlotte/angular2-seed 2
> concurrent "npm run gulp" "npm run lite"

"concurrent" command is deprecated, use "concurrently" instead.

[0]
[0] > angular2-seed@1.0.0 gulp /Users/charlotte/angular2-seed 2
[0] > gulp
[0]
[1]
[1] > angular2-seed@1.0.0 lite /Users/charlotte/angular2-seed 2
[1] > lite-server
[1]
[0] (node:97801) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
[1] Did not detect a `bs-config.json` or `bs-config.js` override file. Using lite-server defaults...
[1] ** browser-sync config **
[1] { injectChanges: false,
[1]   files: [ './**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
[1]   watchOptions: { ignored: 'node_modules' },
[1]   server: { baseDir: './', middleware: [ [Function], [Function] ] } }
[0] /Users/charlotte/angular2-seed 2/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:15
[0]     throw new Error(errors.missingBinary());
[0]     ^
[0]
[0] Error: Missing binding /Users/charlotte/angular2-seed 2/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-48/binding.node
[0] Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Node.js 6.x
[0]
[0] Found bindings for the following environments:
[0]   - OS X 64-bit with Node 0.12.x
[0]
[0] This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
[0] Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to build the binding for your current environment.
[0]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/charlotte/angular2-seed 2/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:15:11)
[0]     at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
[0]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
[0]     at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
[0]     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
[0]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
[0]     at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
[0]     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
[0]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/charlotte/angular2-seed 2/node_modules/gulp-sass/index.js:187:21)
[0]     at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
[0]
[0] npm
[0]  ERR! Darwin 14.1.1
[0] npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.2.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "gulp"
[0] npm ERR! node v6.2.1
[0] npm ERR! npm  v3.10.1
[0] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[0] npm ERR! angular2-seed@1.0.0 gulp: `gulp`
[0] npm ERR!
[0]  Exit status 1
[0] npm ERR!
[0] npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-seed@1.0.0 gulp script 'gulp'.
[0] npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
[0] npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-seed package,
[0] npm ERR! not with npm itself.
[0] npm ERR!
[0]  Tell the author that this fails on your system:
[0] npm ERR!     gulp
[0] npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
[0] npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-seed
[0] npm
[0]  ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
[0] npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-seed
[0] npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
[0]
[0] npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
[0] npm ERR!     /Users/charlotte/angular2-seed 2/npm-debug.log
[0] npm run gulp exited with code 1
```

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34335340/angular2-quickstart-npm-start-is-not-working-correctly?rq=1). The issue was resolved by installing globally using "-g".

Answer (score 1):

this was solved in the same manner as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34335340/angular2-quickstart-npm-start-is-not-working-correctly?rq=1)

I simply ran `sudo npm update -g && sudo npm install -g gulp`

thanks @Shivam

Comment: You may want to reconsider running npm as root https://johnpapa.net/how-to-use-npm-global-without-sudo-on-osx/

Comment: interesting read! i'll give his guide a go and see if i can clean it up. i know it's bad, my laptop has just ended up with all these horrible setting because of work