# Angular 2 - npm3 install typyings errors

Tags: typescript, angular, npm, typescript-typings

Whenever I attempt a sudo npm install Angular 2 modules are updated and installed fine however I get the following when the typings install attempts to run

```
angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.12 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.12 requires a peer of @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN an2_routes@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN an2_routes@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! Darwin 15.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! an2_routes@1.0.0 postinstall: `typings install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the an2_routes@1.0.0 postinstall script 'typings install'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the an2_routes package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     typings install
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs an2_routes
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls an2_routes
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/matthewatwell/Development/webDev/An2_routes/npm-debug.log
```

I have installed npm and typings globally both with elevated permissions

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "an2_routes",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/forms": "0.1.1",
    "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/router":  "3.0.0-alpha.7",
    "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.12",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings":"^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

typings.json

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160602141332",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160621231320"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you behind corporate proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue using the thread linked below

[Angular2 QuickStart npm start is not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34335340/angular2-quickstart-npm-start-is-not-working-correctly)

"Change package.json  "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ", to "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ", worked for me"