# my terminal is showing an "Unknown" while fetching files, when I run npm start

Tags: angular

my terminal is unable to get the files when I run "npm start" and when I make changes to my app, concurrently they are not reflecting on the browsersync. I tried all the solutions provided here "[Angular2 QuickStart npm start is not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34335340/angular2-quickstart-npm-start-is-not-working-correctly)", but still I am unable to get this fixed. I am a beginner learning angular2 on Udemy, please help me out if any of you have any idea regarding this.

Thanks in advance!

[here is the screenshot of my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzkkg.png)

here is package.json

```js
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.6",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^1.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^1.3.1",
    "typescript": "^1.7.3"
  }
}
```

here is index.html

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"></style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/styles.css">
    <style>
        body { padding: 30px; }
    </style>
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: you are using very old version of Angular2. [QuickStartTutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html). Please refer to new package.json and index.html (and other files). Follow steps as instructed.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Sure I will try it out.