# npm install angular-cli throws error (Windows)

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm having a problem with installation of angular-cli on my Windows machine
This is the log of installation. I'm using node v4.4.3 and i have just upgrade it via npm. I have also checked the content of folder `C:\Users\Valor_\AppData\Roaming\npm` and it's not empty. Node is also added to system environment variables. I have also tried to run my CMD as administrator. Same problem appears.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install -g angular-cli
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated lodash-node@2.4.1: This package is discontinued. Use lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@2.2.2: ReDoS vulnerability parsing Set-Cookie https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/130
C:\Users\Valor_\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.14: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "angular-cli"
npm ERR! node v4.4.3
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.0
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Valor_\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-63bb1bbf
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Valor_\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-63bb1bbf' -> 'C:\Users\Valor_\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Valor_\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-63bb1bbf' -> 'C:\Users\Valor_\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\WINDOWS\system32\npm-debug.log

C:\WINDOWS\system32>node -v
v4.4.3
```

So what is wrong? Hove can i fix my problem? If you need any additional information's please let me know and i will provide. Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1190

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me out. Now it's working

```
npm remove -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try the different solutons provided inthis other question :
[Angular2 QuickStart npm start is not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34335340/angular2-quickstart-npm-start-is-not-working-correctly)

It helped me solve this issue when I was followinf this tutorial on Windows 7