# Angular 2 npm start does not work Exit status 1

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-start

I have an angular 2 application on my laptop that works.
But if my teammate clone's it with git he get's a strange error with npm start.
He does have node.js installed and the files are the same.
here is the error message:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v7.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-ser
ver" `
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrentl
y "tsc -w" "lite-server" '.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart pa
ckage,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Timo\Desktop\OOSE Project\Projects\Button_for_Json\npm-deb
ug.log

C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\OOSE Project\Projects\Button_for_Json>npm
```

Comment: Do you have the same version of node/npm on both machines? Did you call `npm install` on the second machine, before calling `npm start`?

Comment: the second machine has a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

In theory **npm start** should go to package.json and start **ng serve**, at least in last angular 2 version.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
```

Do you have that in your package.json?

Anyway look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34335340/angular2-quickstart-npm-start-is-not-working-correctly) . Might be usefull

Comment: I have this there: "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ". I will try you're sulution

Comment: That does not work he gives a different error complaining about ng serve

Comment: Might not have angular-cli installed then.

Comment: I do not have it installed but on my machine it works

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have similar problem like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34335340/angular2-quickstart-npm-start-is-not-working-correctly) question. Could you try their solution?

Basicly you should change the start field in package.json from

```
"start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
```

to

```
"start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
```