# Lite-server npm start wont't work

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, lite-server

I'm completely new to Angular and web programming. Tried to clone the quickstart at github/angular and use "npm start" to start lite-server, as I saw in a tutorial [[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-zW1zHqsdyc&t=804s)] but it doesn't work. Should I change the system's variables or something like so? This is npm's log if it helps:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli       'C:\\Users\\ggysh\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@4.0.5
3 info using node@v6.9.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: angular-quickstart@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: angular-quickstart@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\ggysh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\ggysh\Documents\CodeJS\myapp\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\ggysh\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\ggysh\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit;C:\Users\ggysh\.atom\packages;C:\Program Files (x86)\Ghdl\Bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\MinGW;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit;C:\Users\ggysh\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Users\ggysh\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\ggysh\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
10 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\ggysh\Documents\CodeJS\myapp
11 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" ' ]
12 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" `
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ggysh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:279:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ggysh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid angular-quickstart@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd C:\Users\ggysh\Documents\CodeJS\myapp
17 error Windows_NT 10.0.14393
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ggysh\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
19 error node v6.9.4
20 error npm  v4.0.5
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" `
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" '.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs angular-quickstart
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem, this answer solve it
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37337795/7447071

> Change the start field in package.json from
>
> "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
>   to
>
> "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "