# Angular v2 quickstart error on npm start

Tags: angular

Following angular's Tour of Heroes setup instructions [here](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html), running **npm start** presents me with nothing but this in the web browser:

> Loading AppComponent content here ...

I'm running this on ubuntu desktop inside scotchbox on vagrant.

My output in the console is:

```
 Error: watch /home/vagrant/Documents/quickstart/node_modules/karma/node_modules/lodash/internal/createForEach.js ENOSPC
[1]     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
[1]     at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1443:19)
[1]     at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1470:11)
[1]     at createFsWatchInstance (/home/vagrant/Documents/quickstart/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
[1]     at setFsWatchListener (/home/vagrant/Documents/quickstart/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
[1]     at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/vagrant/Documents/quickstart/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:228:14)
[1]     at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleFile (/home/vagrant/Documents/quickstart/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:255:21)
[1]     at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/Documents/quickstart/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:473:21)
[1]     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
[1] 
[1] npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-75-generic
[1] npm ERR! argv "/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/bin/node" "/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/bin/npm" "run" "serve"
[1] npm ERR! node v6.10.3
[1] npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
[1] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[1] npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 serve: `lite-server -c=bs-config.json`
[1] npm ERR! Exit status 1
[1] npm ERR! 
[1] npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 serve script 'lite-server -c=bs-config.json'.
[1] npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
[1] npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
[1] npm ERR! not with npm itself.
[1] npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
[1] npm ERR!     lite-server -c=bs-config.json
[1] npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
[1] npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-quickstart
[1] npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
[1] npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
[1] npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
[1] 
[1] npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
[1] npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/Documents/quickstart/npm-debug.log
[1] npm run serve exited with code 1
[0] 5:58:03 PM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
```

My node version is 3.10.10 and npm version is v6.10.3.

I'm surprised at how convoluted the information out there on troubleshooting is for an issue that presents itself at the very beginning of this exercise.

Answer (score 0):

I referenced [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34367208/6454901) and ran the following commands to get **npm start** to run without error messages:

```
npm install -g concurrently
npm install -g lite-server
npm install -g typescript
npm uninstall lite-server
```

I'm still presented with the persistent "Loading AppComponent content here ..." message in Chrome Version 67.0.3396.87 (Official Build) (64-bit), but it works correctly in Firefox 60.0.2 (64-bit).